# Printing Prime Numbers Infinite Loop Assembly

Tags: assembly, irvine32

this program is supposed to take a number from the user, and print that many prime numbers. It gets stuck in an infinite loop, and I am at a loss as to why. Any help would be appreciated!

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

;this is the upper limit for the number of terms we will find
UPPER_LIMIT = 200
CHECK_FOR_RETURN = 10 
LOWER_LIMIT = 1
 
.data

; information and prompts
    prompt1 BYTE "Please enter the number of primes to be displayed.", 0
    prompt2 BYTE "You may choose any number between 1 and 200.", 0
    prompt3 BYTE "Please enter a number: ", 0
    rangeError BYTE "You chose a number out of range. ", 0
    space BYTE "  ", 0
    period BYTE ".", 0

; variables
    numTerms DWORD ?
    count DWORD 1
    curr DWORD 2
    checkNum DWORD 0
    divisor DWORD 2

.code
main PROC
    ;get the user data
    call getUserData
    ;display the primes
    call displayPrimes
    exit    ; exit to operating system

main ENDP

getUserData PROC

;prompt the user for a number
userInstruction:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
    call WriteString
    call CrLf
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt2
    call WriteString
    call CrLf
    call CrLf

getNum:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt3
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov numTerms, eax

;check to make sure the number is within the acceptable range
checkMax:
    mov eax, numTerms
    mov ebx, UPPER_LIMIT
    cmp eax, ebx
    jg errorMessage
    jmp checkMin

checkMin:
    mov eax, numTerms
    mov ebx, LOWER_LIMIT
    cmp eax, ebx
    jl errorMessage
    jmp leaveProc

;display an error message if the user picks a number too large
errorMessage:
    mov edx, OFFSET rangeError
    call WriteString
    call CrLf
    call CrLf
    jmp userInstruction

leaveProc:
    RET
getUserData ENDP

displayPrimes PROC
 
 primes:
    ;check to see if the appropriate number of primes has been found
    mov eax, count
    mov ebx, numTerms
    cmp eax, ebx
    jge leaveProc

   ;check the first half of the factors to see if the number is prime
    mov eax, curr
    mov ebx, 2   
    mov edx, 0   
    div ebx
    mov checkNum, eax
    ;loop checkNum times
    mov ecx, checkNum

    ;loop to check primes
    checkForPrimes:
       ;check to see if the current number has a factor 
       mov eax, curr
       mov ebx, divisor
       mov edx, 0
       div ebx
       ;look for a zero remainder
       cmp edx, 0
       ;if the remainder is zero, jump out of the loop and start again with the next number
       je nextNumber
       ;if the remainder was not zero, increment divisor and loop
       inc divisor
       loop checkForPrimes
       
     ;if the divisor is the same as checkNum, the number was prime
     mov eax, divisor
     cmp eax, checkNum
     je printPrime
     
     nextNumber:
        ;incrememnet the current number, and start this process over
        inc curr
        jmp primes  

    leaveProc:
        RET
displayPrimes ENDP

printPrime PROC
    ;print the current number if it was prime
    mov edx, curr
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET space
    call WriteString
    inc count
    ret
printPrime ENDP


END main
```

I used Visual Studio 2019for this program, and I've tried the debugging option, but I still can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: Your debugger should at least show you *where* the program gets stuck, right?

Comment: Stuck in *which* loop?  If you already used a debugger to single-step it, include that info in your [mcve].

Comment: `je printPrime`: if this jump is taken, the `ret` in `printPrime` takes you back to the caller of `displayPrimes`, i.e. back to `main`, which I don't think is what you want.